# Simple mod_rewrite for search querystring

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I am trying to rewrite

```
/search?keyword=foobar
```

to

```
/search/foobar
```

without much success.

I currently have the following which seem to produce a 404:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^keyword=(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* /search/%1? [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a resource at `/search/foobar` then of course you're going to get a 404. Two entirely different things are happening here. The server has a physical resource that gets served (or a script that runs) that apache knows about. If apache sees `/search/foobar`, it is going to look for a directory called "search" and either a directory or a file called "foobar". If it sees neither, it's going to return a 404. The other part of what's happening is the browser, completely separate from apache, sees a URL (e.g. `/search/foobar`) and does what it needs to do in order to request for the resource. It talks to the webserver and asks for `/search/foobar`.

When the request comes in, it's up to the URL-file processing pipeline to turn that into a file which points to where the resource is. If mod_rewrite takes the URL and rewrites it to `/blah/blah/blah`, there better be a directory called `/blah/blah` and a file in there called `blah` or else it's going to 404.

Your rules are saying, if an incoming request is for anything with the query string `?keyword=(something)`, then redirect the browser to `/search/(something)`. The browser sees this, and does what it's supposed to do; it sends **another request** for `/search/(something)`. Apache's going to see this and wonder what the request is all about, not knowing what the request is for, and return 404.

What you probably want is to first, handle the `/search/(something)` URI's

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?search/(.*)$ /search?keyword=$1 [L,QSA]
```

So when a request comes in as `/search/foobar`, the rewrite engine internally rewrites it to something apache can understand, `/search?keyword=foobar`. This internal rewrite happens entirely on the server, the browser is ignorant of it.

Now, when a form is submitted as a GET method, you'll end up with a `?keyword=(something)` in the URL, and it looks like you're trying to get rid of that. So apache gets the query string, and there must be something to redirect the browser to the nicer looking URL, at which point the browser does its thing, submits a brand new request, which gets internally rewritten by the above rule back to what it should be.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?keyword=([^\ &]+)&?([^\ ]*)
RewriteRule ^ /search/%1?%2 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: it still seem to produce a 404 although the 301 seem to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I sorted it out with the following:

```
RewriteRule search/(.*)$ /search?keyword=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?keyword=([^\ &]+)&?([^\ ]*)
RewriteRule ^ /search/%1?%2 [L,R=301]
```

but not quite. Having issues where there are multiple querystrings or some other URLs containing `search/` in the URL, eg. /search/css/foobar.css?version=152